# Flex: make part of a skin non focusable/non-clickable

Tags: flash, apache-flex, button, flex4, skin

AKA: How to set the hitArea in a skin.

I need to make part of a flex skin non-focusable/non-clickable, i.e. so that when the mouse clicks that part of the button, it doesn't actually get clicked.

Basically, I want that part to be a shadow or highlight or background or whatever you'd like to call it.  It's done somehow with drop shadows but I want to have finer control than using filters.

Example code:

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" >
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
            [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>
    <s:Ellipse id="nonFocusableBackground"
        left="-20" right="-20" bottom="-20" top="-20">
        ...
    </s:Ellipse>

    <s:Rect id="focusableForeground" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        ...
    </s:Rect>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

With this code I want the part with the id nonFocusableBackground to not be part of the skin/component's active area (my own term).  Currently, however, this part, since it is bigger than the other part, will click the button when it is clicked.

I have done a quick test using a halo effect, which produces decent results, but it's not quite what I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the simplest way to do it. I would really like to have a way to do all of this directly in mxml.

Here's how I solved it for now:

in skin declaration:

```
creationComplete="setHitArea(event)"
```

in script:

```
protected function setHitArea(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        this.clickGroup.mouseEnabled = false;
        this.hitArea = this.clickGroup;
        this.hostComponent.hitArea = this.clickGroup;
    }
```

rest:

```
<s:Group id="clickGroup" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:Rect id="focusableForeground" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    ...
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't believe that graphic primitives accept focus.  They have no focus events; and how would a user tell something was in focus?  What have you been experiencing?

You could put your Shape in a UIComponent and then use the UIComponent and use [focusEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#focusEnabled) and [hasFocusableChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#hasFocusableChildren) to false.

Comment: @jordeox Why would the fact that these are in a Skin matter?  So far as I knew graphic primitives don't suddenly have the ability to accept focus just because you put them in a skin.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, they do, since they're then part of a button component.

Comment: @jordoex I'm not sure what you think you're seeing.  I'm reviewing the Spark Button code and see no proof that graphic primitives can accept focus.  A Spark Button extends UIComponent and that button can accept focus and mouse movements.  The graphics in the Spark Button skin do not.  They are changed based on the skin state, which are modified due to mouse events.

Comment: I meant hit area and not really focus, since I didn't know what to call hit area when I first asked this question.  And as they are part of the button, they are part of the button's focus stuff.  That's what's happening.